# OAuth access_denied on login from all providers after server IP change

Tags: facebook, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

We recently changed the IP-address on a server hosting one of our services based on .NET Web API 2.

The service is using OAuth2, providing external logins via Facebook/Google.

We're still using the same server and the same host name for our services, only the IP-address has changed. Now I'm getting back my login URL with "&error=access_denied" whenever I try to login using Facebook/Google.

I have checked every setting in both Facebook's and Google's developer consoles but nothing seems to apply. If I remove the OAuth redirect URI, I get an error that the URL is blocked, so the settings seems to take effect.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Funny how asking a question makes you think even more outside of the box. The culprit was that wrong DNS-server was set on the web host.

I'll see myself out...